# How can I deploy an asp.net application using Visual Studio 2008

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

I am trying to publish a website using IIS, I made a virtual directory and in this directory I've added all the webpages and configured the virtual directory but still I am not able to run my web application.

Comment: What error message do you see in the browser when you attempt to view your web application?

Answer (score 5):

Here is the step by step method to deploy an asp.net application

http://www.15seconds.com/issue/030806.htm

Please post any error message

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that your are running the right asp.net Version...
check if in the asp.net tab if it's v 1 change it to v2

Answer (score 1):

Could you please let me know the error message.( Check with minimum settings like startUp page , version, try publishing with Wizards etc)

Answer (score 1):

In Visual studio, click on **project**, **Properties**, **Web**.
Under **Servers**, select **Use local IIS Web server**, then on **Create virtual Directory**.
Now, when you debug, the page should open in IIS, and Visual studio has taken care of most of the grudge work of setting up the IIS, all you will probably have to change is the security settings under IIS. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

If it is IIS7 check that your application has enough permissions to run:

IIS Actions Pane:

1. Basic Settings
2. Connect as (be sure to log in with Admin account first to test, then create you own specific user. Least Privilege Principle)
3. Test Settings (Authorization and Authentication is Green!)
4. Test your webisite

Answer (score 1):

The question doesn't say what exactly the error is but you mentioned that you just created the virtual directory. Did you make it an web application? For IIS 6 follow this
[**link - Create and Configure Local ASP.NET Web Sites**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/33487zw6.aspx). In IIS7 just right click on it and convert it to application.

If its already a website, did you choose the correct framework? normally when you create a website it ill be assigned the default app-pool. If you have installed multiple dotnet then you might check which framework is in default app-pool. Then change the default app-pool to the correct version that is required by your website, or create a new app-pool.

There can be multiple reasons so if you could provide the error message then it would be easier to resolve the problem.

Thanks.